# Increasing work code number +1 every two weeks out of year?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have dates in column A. I am starting with 3/1/24 and eventually will fill dates all the way to 12/31/24. Every two weeks I want to increase the last 000 code of work number by +1.

Example, date range 3/1/24-3/15/24 would be ERE-2024-004. date range 3/16/24-3/30/24 would be ERE-2024-005, and so on for every 2 weeks out of the year.

Formula I tried:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKNUM(A1, 2) >= WEEKNUM(DATE(2024, 1, 1), 2), WEEKNUM(A1, 2) <= 
WEEKNUM(EOMONTH(A1, 0), 2)), "ERE-2024-" & TEXT(INT((WEEKNUM(A1, 2) - 
WEEKNUM(DATE(2024, 1, 1), 2) + 1) / 2) + 3, "000"), "Out of Range")
```

Getting a #VALUE error:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does this work for you? `="ERE-2024-"&TEXT(INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A84),,4,1/15)),"000")`

Comment: If you meant every half month (2 weeks are 14 days) i.e. from the 1st to the 15th and the 16th to the end of a month, you could use `="ERE-"&YEAR(A2)&"-"&TEXT(2*MONTH(A2)-(DAY(A2)<16),"000")` or `="ERE-"&YEAR(A2:A307)&"-"&TEXT(2*MONTH(A2:A307)-(DAY(A2:A307)<16),"000")` to spill, covering until the end of the year. If not, explain in more detail.

Comment: @VBasic2008 So this works, but is there any way to have it offset by -1 in the 00x part of the formula? It spits out "005" at the end for 3/1/24-3/15/24, which is correct, but we started the 00x tracking on 1/15 of this year so there have only been 4 bi-weeks for us instead of 5

Comment: Just use `... 16)-1,...`.

Comment: Have you tried the one posted in `Answer` it seems a very simple way explained and nicely put up or the one I have commented?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not using any standard week of year numbering, so I would ignore any built in Excel functions to determine which week a date is in.  To begin, you have a start date (3/1/2024), a period (15 days) and a start group number (4) and these are your inputs (B1, B2 and B3).

[image]

You can calculate a week number by subtracting your start date (B1) from any given future date (A1) and dividing by the period to see which "week" it is in.  We round down because until we advance at least one whole number, we are still in the same week.  Lastly we add on what the first week number we want is (you are using 4 in your example).

`=FLOOR.MATH((A5-$B$1)/$B$2)+$B$3`

You can then concatenate that together and format.

`="ERE-"&YEAR(A5)&"-"&TEXT(B5,"000")`

You end up with something like this.

[image]